# save Facebook information in my remote data base with titanium

Tags: json, facebook, titanium

I want to ask I have developed a mobile application which you can login using Facebook username and password so I want to know how can I save the username and password from Facebook into my remote database.

This is my code any help please:

```
var fb = require('facebook'); fb.appid = "281158112043247";
// Set the URL 

fb.permissions = ['email'];
fb.authorize();

fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        fb.requestWithGraphPath('me', {}, 'GET', function(e) {
            if (e.success) {
               var data= JSON.parse(e.result);
              xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
               xhr.open(&quot;Post&quot;, &quot;http://192.168.131.145:5220/Create.svc/createClient&quot;);
               var params = {
                Clientusername: data.name,
                //password:password1.value,
            //  Clientpassword: Ti.Utils.md5HexDigest(password1.value),
                Clientnom: data.name,
                Clientid:data.id,
                Clientemail: data.email
            };
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        //xhr.send(e.result);
                Ti.API.info(&quot;Name:&quot;+data.name);
                Ti.API.info(&quot;email:&quot;+data.email);
                Ti.API.info(&quot;facebook Id:&quot;+data.id);   
            } else if (e.error) {
                alert(e.error);
            } else {
                alert('Unknown response.');
            }
        });// request graph
    }else{
        if(e.error){
            alert(e.error);
        }else{
            alert(&quot;Unkown error while trying to login to facebook.&quot;);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to their Facebook password. The oauth specifically protects against you having to know their access credentials. It allows Facebook to separately identify you, and what you are doing with the API. The user can also then disable your access to their data, if they see fit. But if you had their password, you could do anything that they can do, even temporarily steal their account. Plus their account would only be as secure as your storage of their password (is it encrypted? are you servers secure? on premise? compromised? running any malware?). So generally, no, it's a bad idea, don't do that, even if you figure out a way to do so.

In the case of your code above, you have already authorized the user inside your app, so you won't need to authorize them again. They'll already be logged in. You should check `if (fb.loggedIn)` and then do your logged-in-only code, `else fb.authorize();`.

Comment: thnx  for your answer but I am not going  to save facbook password also facebook doesn't give you the permise to take the password,my idea it is about when a client connectto my application with facebook i want to save his email and his name in my data base in order to have an acces in his profile in my application that is all

Comment: So basically, the question you asked, "how can I save the username and password", isn't your question? And you have no other stated problem or error you're hitting? It's going to be really difficult to help you, then.